# How do you set a static IP address for a Google Container Engine (GKE) service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

A little bit of background: I have a Go service that uses gRPC to communicate with client apps. gRPC uses HTTP2, so I can't use Google App Engine or the Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer. I need raw TCP load balancing from the internet to my Go application.

I went through the GKE tutorials and read the various docs and I can't find any way to give my application a static IP address. So how do you get a static IP attached to something running in GKE?

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported in kubernetes v1.0.x but in v1.1.x it will be available as `service.spec.loadBalancerIP`.  As long as you actually own that IP we will use it.

Comment: I am trying to use 'loadBalancerIP' on my GKE (v1.1.1) service. Created a static IP address in the cloud console and added it to the service definition. Still, the service gets a different IP address and the static IP remains unassigned - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: post your YAML or JSON, please?  Also please run `kubectl get service <name> -o yaml` so we can see what the server thinks it got.

Comment: Wild guess: I suspect you have an older kubectl commandline (I think the gcloud bundled version is waiting for a new gcloud push)

Comment: You were right, I updated the command line tools to 1.1.1! However, it's still not working. 'kubectl get': https://gist.github.com/mlamina/9c553f0734cae16e0fc5. My yaml definition of the service: https://gist.github.com/mlamina/d8054f6765bcc9339737

Comment: Weird.  Can you run kubectl with --validate ?

Comment: "kubectl create -f backend/api/ssl-proxy-production.yml --validate" ran without any error messages!

Comment: I am flummoxed.  I just tried to repro, and it works fine on my cluster (from head last week).  Are you SURE the kubectl you are running is not some back-rev version that happens to be in $PATH?  That's the only way I can see this happening

Comment: Alright I tried everything (even rebooting my laptop) and now I'm getting this: "Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service production/api-lb: this gce project doesn't own the IP address: [MY-PUBLIC-IP]" - even though I just created it in the GCE console with "Reserve static IP"

Comment: Are you sure that the cluster is in the same project as the static IP address you created? Are you sure that the cluster is in the same region as the static IP address?

Comment: Damn, it's working now. I always set the type to "Global", but apparently it needs to be "Regional"? Why is that?

Comment: @MarcoLamina Your comment needs to be in a separate answer since this is the right way to go

Comment: @MarcoLamina I'm pretty sure its because the type of load balancer (TCP) created by kubernetes doesn't support global types.  You have to use a http load balancer for that.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually figured this out. To do this, you ask GKE to set up an external load balancer for you, then you selectively replace pieces of the stack. The good news is that along the way you can also set up HTTP health checking, which GKE doesn't do by default.

Make sure you have a static IP available from Google Cloud Platform. You can request on in the Console.

Get your service up and running with something like:

```
kubectl expose rc api-server --name=api-server --port=8080,8081 --create-external-load-balancer=true
```

(I'm using port 8080 for HTTP health checking and 8081 to serve gRPC requests).

`--create-external-load-balancer=true` updates the Kubernetes services with an ingress rule, sets up a target pool, sets up a network load balancer and adds a firewall rule. We're going to have to fix #1 and #3.

Figure out where everything is running already.

```
export TARGET_POOL_NAME=$(gcloud compute target-pools list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1)

export EXTERNAL_IP=$(gcloud compute addresses list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 3)
```

Attach the health check to the target pool

```
gcloud compute http-health-checks create api-server-http-basic-check --port 8080 --request-path "/_health"

gcloud compute target-pools add-health-checks ${TARGET_POOL_NAME} --http-health-check api-server-http-basic-check
```

Create a new forwarding rule to replace the one generated by GKE

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create api-server \
--region us-central1 --port-range 8080-8081 \
--address ${EXTERNAL_IP} --target-pool ${TARGET_POOL_NAME}
```

Delete the original GKE forwarding rule

```
 gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete $(gcloud compute forwarding-rules list | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

Update the Kubernetes Service to allow ingress from the new IP:

```
kubectl patch services api-server -p "{\"status\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"ingress\": [{\"ip\": \"${EXTERNAL_IP}\"} ]}}}"
```

That should do it!

*Be careful with copy pasting, my heads and tails work for me because I only have one app running, but you might see things in a different order.*

Comment: Zach -- I'm glad you were able to figure this out. When you create a service in GKE, you should be able to request that it be assigned to a specific IP address. So if you create a static IP, you should be able to have that assigned to your service.

Comment: Thanks for the response @RobertBailey! I see that as a command line flag to kubctl expose.  Where do I put the public-ip in my *_controller.json if I'm using `kubectl create`? 

I think I still need to reach in to attach the http health check, so exploring how it was set up ended up being really informative.

Comment: I think that deprecatedPublicIPs is the field you want (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L1534-L1539) but it could be the new externalIPs field above it. And this goes in your *_service.json file, not the replication controller configuration.

Comment: @RobertBailey: I don't think this works unfortunately. I tried the command line version with `kubectl expose rc api-server-controller --name=api-server --port=8081 --create-external-load-balancer=true --public-ip="146.148.83.156"`.  When I run `kubectl get -o json services api-server` it shows the ip address in `"deprecatedPublicIPs": [
            "146.148.83.156"
        ],`, but `gcloud compute addresses list` still shows the address as reserved, not used. `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list` shows that it picked up an ephemeral address.