# Error creating load balancer with static IP on GKE with stable/traefik chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik, kubernetes-helm

Using GKE and helm stable/traefik.

When releasing to my cluster with a static IP for the `loadBalancerIP` I get the following error:

```
Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load 
balancer for service kube-system/rp-traefik: requested ip <my-ip> 
is neither static nor assigned to LB 
af5bfb5bd94a211e7adce42010a8e00e(kube-system/rp-traefik): <nil>
```

Three things seem important:

1. no matter how many times I run this (even after I've manually deleted all the LB's in my GCE. It always looks for LB `af5bfb5bd94a211e7adce42010a8e00e`. Where is this key coming from?
2. running `gcloud compute addresses list` shows `<my-ip>` as `RESERVED` so it should be available.
3. when I update the helm release values with a blank `loadBalancerIP` the `af5bfb5bd94a211e7adce42010a8e00e` LB is successfully created. When I change back to the static IP (after the target LB exists) it fails with the same error again.

I'm stuck. What would you check/try next?

Answer (score 1):

Your static IP type should be `Regional`, which GKE Load balancer does not support Global type.

Reference: comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33251143/411518